# How to train a LSTM model on the fly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I have a LSTM model that is used to create a Chatbot. The Chatbot now knows how to respond from whatever it knows based on its trained model.

So, now we have a situation that our chat bot should *learn dynamically as and when a new query is posted which the chat bot has no idea about*, it should learn from the query and the response and add it to its trained model.

Could someone tell me how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by simply loading your saved model (which you probably saved with `model.save()`) and training your new data with `fit()` method, something like:

```py
from keras.models import load_model
#load your model
model = load_model('chatbot.h5')
#Continue training with your new data, adding parameters as needed
model.fit(X2, Y2, epochs=20)
```

Comment: No, my chat bot is online always. we dont want to load the trained model and fit new ones from the start. When online, i want to feed new data to it.

Comment: @prabhu what do you mean with 'when online'? Surely you have your .h5 model trained for which you are calling `predict()` ... well you can refit *that* model "on the fly" while online after you get new data and labels, doing as explained in my answer. Does that work for you, if not, mind explaining a bit more?

Comment: let's say, i had trained my chatbot to answer questions related to a specific topic, ex: 'a ferrari car'. Now, if i ask a question to my chat bot like 'what is the output torque of a lamborgini?'. Chatbot definitely fail to answer this. question. Now, i will have a corpus (rather smaller in size), that will contain text data about lamborgini car. I want to train the chatbot with this data without stopping the chatbot service. How to achieve this is my question

Comment: I think you're completely overestimating what a simple lstm can do. Unless you have a large **labelled** corpus, or use sophisticated NLP techniques, what you are asking is in the realm of science fiction. You can't just feed it text and expect it to "understand".

Comment: @prabhu you can do that as explained before. Say you get the 'what is the output torque of a lambo'. For you to be able to train your model "dynamically" (which is called Online Learning), you will have to **somehow obtain the label of that new text**, and then **fit it to your `model`, with text as data and label obtained**. That way your chatbot can still learn without having to stop it. Now, as you can see the actual problem here is **getting that label**, which is a challenging AI task by itself. Assuming you can do that you can also train your chatbot dynamically.

Comment: @DarkCygnus. Thanks for your inputs guys. will implement what you have told.

Comment: @prabhu glad I could help :) consider upvoting if any answer was useful to you